# Spring Security and OSGi

Tags: spring-security, osgi, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to create a simple example using Spring Security 3.1.3 on Virgo 3.6.0.M03.
The example consists of 3 bundles:

- security bundle configuring and publishing an AuthenticationManager

  ```
  <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
     <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
           <security:user name="Rigas" password="password" authorities="ROLE_MEMBER"/>
        </security:user-service>
     </security:authentication-provider>
  </security:authentication-manager>
  <service id="authenticationManagerOsgi" ref="authenticationManager" interface="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager"/>
  ```
- helloSecurity bundle publishing a secured helloWorld method. It references the AuthenticationManager and injects it in global-method-security.

  ```
  <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
  <reference id="authenticationManager" availability="mandatory" interface="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager"/>
  <service id="helloSpringSecurityOsgi" ref="helloSpringSecurity" interface="net.ansible.examples.hellospringsecurity.HelloSpringSecurity" />
  ```
- helloSecurityConsumer bundle referencing the helloSecurity IF and calling the secured helloWorld method.

  ```
  <reference id="helloSpringSecurity" availability="mandatory" interface="net.ansible.examples.hellospringsecurity.HelloSpringSecurity"/>
  ```

Bundle statup and wiring work properly, but once helloSecurityConsumer calls the secured method the following exception is thrown:

```
Failed to call secure method org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'authenticationManager' must be of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager], but was actually of type [$Proxy94]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.security.config.method.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java:386)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:202)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at net.ansible.examples.hellospringsecurity.impl.HelloSpringSecurityImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$99e49c75.sayHello(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:56)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy95.sayHello(Unknown Source)
at net.ansible.examples.hellospringsecurityconsumer.impl.HelloSpringSecurityConsumerImpl$MyRunnable.run(HelloSpringSecurityConsumerImpl.java:50)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser attempts to use the referenced AuthenticationManager and has a problem converting the Proxy around the OSGi refeternce to a ProviderManager. 
Debugging shows the Proxy (a jdkDynamicAopProxy) is indeed a proxy around the ProviderManager class and has all the relevant interfaces.
Is there a working configuration to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. Line 386 of the file [GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/method/GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.java?hb=true) that raises the error is

```
delegate = beanFactory.getBean(authMgrBean, ProviderManager.class);
```

It asks the bean factory for an bean with the concrete implementation `ProviderManager`, but it should only request a bean with the interface `AuthenticationManager` like:

```
delegate = beanFactory.getBean(authMgrBean, AuthenticationManager.class);
```

You may want to raise a ticket in [Spring Security's Jira](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC).

BTW: We are also exporting the authenticationManager as an OSGI service and consume it in other bundles, which works really well.

Comment: I just remembered that I opened a bug report a while ago that had a similar issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1842
(http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?116363). We also hit a problem where a ProviderManager instance was expected instead of just an AuthenticationManager implementation. So there may be other places in the code where ProviderManager instead of AuthenticationManager is used.

Comment: You are right. Patching the GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser makes everything work properly.